# Mongoose upsert without deleting existing fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The goal of my code is to upsert an object into my database. I created the Schema which is a bit complex

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const objectSchema = new Schema(
    { message: String },
    { discriminatorKey: "type", _id: false }
);

const cameraSchema = new Schema(
    {
        number: { type: Number, required: true },
        name: { type: String, required: true } //Do not update if exists
    },
    { _id: false }
);

const mainSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
        lastUpdateTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        objects: [objectSchema]
    },
    { collection: "mainCollection" }
);

mainSchema.path("objects").discriminator(
    "TypeA",
    new Schema(
        {
            cameras: [cameraSchema],
            enabled: { type: Boolean } //Do not update if exists
        },
        { _id: false }
    )
);

mainSchema.path("objects").discriminator(
    "TypeB",
    new Schema(
        {
            available: { type: Boolean, required: true },
            enabled: { type: Boolean } //Do not update if exists
        },
        { _id: false }
    )
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("mainModel", mainSchema);
```

I am receiving the following object from an external source

```
{
  "name": "040C7",
  "objects": [
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "cameras": [
        {
          "number": 1
        },
        {
          "number": 2
        },
        {
          "number": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "available": false
    }
  ]
}
```

If the name exists in my database, I should update every field that I received without removing/updating the fields :

- `enabled` in *TypeA* and *TypeB*
- `name` in the camera objects

Otherwise, I should insert it in the database with all the fields and default values for `enabled` (true) and `name` (Camera)

---

I already tried the `UpdateOne()` function but it is deleting my fields `enabled` and `name` when they already are in my database

```
const obj = new myModel(message);

let upsertObj = obj.toObject();

delete upsertRcm._id;

MyModel.updateOne(
    { name: obj.name },
    upsertObj,
    { upsert: true },
    err => {
        console.log(err)
    }
);
```

How can I say to mongoose to keep fields that are already in my database but not in my received object ?

Document in database

```
{
  "lastUpdateTime": "2018-11-07T09:12:30.750Z",
  "name": "040C7",
  "objects": [
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "enabled": true,
      "cameras": [
        {
          "number": 1,
          "name": "Camera",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "enabled": true,
      "available": false
    }
  ]
}
```

After the update with the received object

```
{
  "lastUpdateTime": "2018-11-07T09:14:30.600Z",
  "name": "040C7",
  "objects": [
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "cameras": [
        {
          "number": 1,
        },
        {
          "number": 2,
        },
        {
          "number": 3,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "available": false
    }
  ]
}
```

But it should be

```
{
  "lastUpdateTime": "2018-11-07T09:14:30.600Z",
  "name": "040C7",
  "objects": [
    {
      "type": "TypeA",
      "enabled": true
      "cameras": [
        {
          "number": 1,
          "name": "Camera"
        },
        {
          "number": 2,
        },
        {
          "number": 3,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "TypeB",
      "enabled": true,
      "available": false
    }
  ]
}
```

MongoDB version: 4.0.2

The `name` field is my unique identifier. Only one type "TypeA", "TypeB", ... will be present in the array. I will never receive 2 "TypeA" in my objects

The list of fields that have to be updated :

- `objects["TypeA"].cameras.number` (value from new object)
- `objects["TypeB"].available` (value from new object)
- `lastUpdateTime` (Date now)

The list of fields that are in the database and should kept :

- `objects["TypeA"].enabled`
- `objects["TypeA"].cameras.name`
- `objects["TypeB"].enabled`

Comment: Please show a reproducible example of what you see happening and show what you expect to happen where an update occurs on an existing document. I suspect you basically mean to "merge" or "push" new entries to the array, but an example of what you expect to happen makes all intentions clear. Please also refrain from marking whole sentences in **bold** as it will not get result in your question being answered any sooner.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for the comment. I edited my question with the current behavior and what I except. I am sorry for the bold question, it was only to make it more visible in the large block of text that is my question.

Comment: So to rephrase your question. *You want to match each item in the `"objects"` array for the matched document based on the `"type"` field for each object, and then "merge" the provided fields with the existing fields.*. Sound right? Also what is the version of MongoDB on the server?

Comment: Trying to prompt you to be as "specific" as possible here. How is the update going to match the array entries? You turned off the `_id` so now your array members lack a unique identifier. That would be okay if something else is unique, but I'm expecting that it probably is not. And to be clear here what you are expecting by simply supplying the received object and having everything "just merge itself" is not what happens here. So you need to be clear on the rules and how things are going to match in order to update. So were waiting!

Comment: @NeilLunn I updated the asked information. Thanks for helping me !

Comment: @NeilLunn The `enabled` and `name` fields are added by a website later on